# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in windows container

Tags: docker-for-windows

I am trying to containerize an existing application, where we pass certificates for authentication when calling different services.
I have installed the certificates in the container.
However, when calling the services, it gives the below exception.

Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Answer (score 0):

Passing this while importing certificate solved the problem.
X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet